# How to fix error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed even though I close my code exactly like the tutorial?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am coding a very simple java program and meet this error : "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed" As you can see in this picture

[image: my problem]

In my problem's picture, as you can see, I have been closed my code by this code

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="DiamonShop"></context:component-scan>
```

So I do not know why I have this error ?

Here is all my code, if you need to reference

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/DiamonShop4.4
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `<beans` ends with `/>` rather than `>` - so that ends the beans and you can't have anything outside of that root element so the rest is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You self-ended your root element, "beans", back on line 10. Move your cursor into the various names of the start tags and you'll see.